# How to center align the nomenclature output?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nomenclature

I am using `nomencl` package to generate the List of Abbreviations which is working fine and is giving me the results. The problem is that I want the results to be centered on the page and not left flushed.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what is the desired final layout?

Comment: No MWE so 'unclear': please edit one in.